# c# XML serialization assigning value to element

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Im trying to get my XML to look like it does below

```
<Assets>
  <Asset id="" Type="" name="" filename="">filepath</Asset>  
  <Asset id="" Type="" name="" filename="">filepath</Asset>            
</Assets>
```

What i have currently is

```
public class Main
{    
    public List<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
}

public class Asset
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "filename")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

The Class Main isn't important, this is a small snippet from a bigger object.

what im having issues with is getting the filepath to be the value of the asset element

in its current state the XML looks like

```
<Assets>
  <Asset id="" Type="" name="" filename="">
    <FilePath>filepath</FilePath>
  </Asset>
  <Asset id="" Type="" name="" filename="">
    <FilePath>filepath</FilePath>
  </Asset>
</Assets>
```

Comment: check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`XmlTextAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
[XmlText]
public string FilePath { get; set; }
```